# Xamarin forms: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I am converting my `PCL` project to `.Net Standard` project using [this](https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/) article. But getting the following error when building.

[image]

I try adding `netstandard` reference like below from [this](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542) thread, but no luck.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

**Complete Error Details**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

**Please suggest any solution to this problem?**

I didn't find `netstandard` reference on there, is it have any other name? screenshot of my `reference manager` added below.

[image]

Initialy, I got another error from windows part.
Error details:

> Severity   Code    Description Myproject   File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1201  Project Myproj is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Project Myproject supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)   Myproject.UW

Choosing the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update for both Target and Min version for my UWP app solved the above problem. I got this from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93522/uwp-uap10015063-not-compatible-with-net-standard-2.html). Is that fix affect the current error?

Comment: why do you edit the csproj. Can't you add it via "add Reference" ?

Comment: also, the warning in your image clearly says that your changes to the csproj are not correct !

Comment: @FelixD. `netstandard` is not available in reference manager, I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: @FelixD. Actualy I am converting the PCL project to .Net standard project, I followed the steps on the article by Montemagno. https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/

Comment: Well it says add the packages so did you add all the packages back?

Comment: I've learned the hard way it is easier to create a new project (netstandard) and then move all classes and stuff. The conversion is aweful !

Comment: @G.hakim All the packages are already there, I am not add anyone

Comment: Well then you are clearly doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the package correctly,

Delete your csproj, it should look  look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<PackageReference Include="" Version=""/>-->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And after this, go to open packages.config, and add the package references above,

```
<PackageReference Include="YourPackageName" Version="XYZ"/>
```

The last step, delete `AssemblyInfo.cs` and `packages.config`

If this doesn't work, and if you are using Visual studio for Mac you can use
[Mutatio](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio)

The last available option is to create a brand new project, netstandard and the copy the classes and files from your old one.

Comment: I am following the steps on the article by Montemagno.https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/

Comment: Already completed all those steps you suggested from the article. After that when I build I am getting the above error.

Comment: Initially, I got another error, I added that details in the question now, can you please check? Is that fix affect the current error?